# scrreprt thumb indices with scrlayer-scrpage: use any shape as chapterthumb

Tags: koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage, chapterthumb

I would like to use a different shape than a rectangle as chapterthumb-symbol, i.e. a circle or a diamond with rounded corners. Is this possible at all using scrlayer-scrpage and a two-sided scrreprt setup? I saw that one can draw shapes in LaTeX using Tikz, how could I implement this with the setup I have?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, openright, BCOR=1cm, headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[paperheight=24cm, paperwidth=17cm, inner=2.3cm, outer=1.6cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=1.9cm,footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%%%---header/footer
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

%%--"Chapter #" in lehead (only for numbered chapters), chapter name in rohead
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{%
    \markboth{\ifnumbered{chapter}{\chaptermarkformat}{}}{#1}%
}

\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\markboth{}{\contentsname}}

\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{empty} %% no header or page numbers on chapter title pages


%%%---thumb indices using chapterthumb

% the following bases on an example in the KOMA-Script book:
\newcommand*{\firstchapterthumbskip}{.1\paperheight}
\newcommand*{\lastchapterthumbskip}{\firstchapterthumbskip}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbheight}{2em}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbwidth}{.1\paperheight}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbskip}{.1\paperheight}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbboxcolor}{gray!30}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbcolor}{white}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbformat}{\thechapter}
\newkomafont{chapterthumb}{\normalfont\Large\color{\chapterthumbcolor}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\chapterthumb@box{%
    \parbox[c][\chapterthumbheight][c]{\chapterthumbwidth}{%
        \centering\usekomafont{chapterthumb}{\chapterthumbformat}%
    }%
}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbbox}{%
    \if@mainmatter
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>\z@
    \ifnum \value{chapterthumb}<\z@
    \else
    \begingroup
    \protected@edef\reserved@a{\chapterthumbformat}%
    \ifx\reserved@a\lastchapterthumbformat\else
    \stepcounter{chapterthumb}%
    \global\let\lastchapterthumbformat\reserved@a
    \fi
    \@tempcnta=\numexpr 
    \dimexpr 
    \paperheight
    -\firstchapterthumbskip
    -\chapterthumbwidth
    -\lastchapterthumbskip
    \relax / \dimexpr 
    \chapterthumbskip 
    \relax
    +1
    \relax
    \ifnum \value{chapterthumb}<\@tempcnta
    \else
    \setcounter{chapterthumb}{0}%
    \fi
    \vspace*{%
        \dimexpr 
        \firstchapterthumbskip
        + ( \chapterthumbskip )
        * \value{chapterthumb}%
        - \baselineskip
        \relax
    }\par
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
    \ifodd\value{page}
    \hfill
    \makebox[0pt][r]{%
        \rotatebox[origin=tr]{90}{%
            \colorbox{\chapterthumbboxcolor}{%
                \parbox[t][\chapterthumbheight]{\chapterthumbwidth}{%
                    \chapterthumb@box
                    \vskip3mm
    }}}}%
    \else
    \hspace*{-3mm}%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
        \rotatebox[origin=tr]{90}{%
            \colorbox{\chapterthumbboxcolor}{%
                \parbox{\chapterthumbwidth}{%
                    \vskip3mm
                    \chapterthumb@box
    }}}}%
    \fi
    \endgroup
    \fi
    \fi
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{chapterthumb}
\setcounter{chapterthumb}{10000}
\newcommand*{\lastchapterthumbformat}{\relax}

\DeclareNewLayer[%
background,%
outermargin,%
contents=\chapterthumbbox
]{chapterthumb}

\newcommand*\EnableChapterthumb{%
    \IfLayerAtPageStyle{scrheadings}{chapterthumb}{}
    {\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb}}%
}
\newcommand*\DisableChapterthumb{%
    \RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb}%
}

\EnableChapterthumb

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\lipsum[1-6]

\chapter{Second}

\lipsum[7-12]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *would appear* to be possible.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, openright, BCOR=1cm, headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[paperheight=24cm, paperwidth=17cm, inner=2.3cm, outer=1.6cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=1.9cm,footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

%%%---header/footer
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

%%--"Chapter #" in lehead (only for numbered chapters), chapter name in rohead
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{%
    \markboth{\ifnumbered{chapter}{\chaptermarkformat}{}}{#1}%
}

\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\markboth{}{\contentsname}}

\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{empty} %% no header or page numbers on chapter title pages


%%%---thumb indices using chapterthumb

% the following bases on an example in the KOMA-Script book:
\newcommand*{\firstchapterthumbskip}{.1\paperheight}
\newcommand*{\lastchapterthumbskip}{\firstchapterthumbskip}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbheight}{3em}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbwidth}{.1\paperheight}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbskip}{.1\paperheight}
\colorlet{chapterthumbboxcolor}{gray!30}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbcolor}{white}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbformat}{\thechapter}
\newkomafont{chapterthumb}{\normalfont\Large\color{\chapterthumbcolor}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\chapterthumb@box{%
  \usekomafont{chapterthumb}%
    \parbox[c][\chapterthumbheight][c]{\chapterthumbwidth}{%
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[circle, inner sep=1.3ex, fill=chapterthumbboxcolor]
          {\chapterthumbformat};
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
}
\newcommand*{\chapterthumbbox}{%
    \if@mainmatter
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>\z@
    \ifnum \value{chapterthumb}<\z@
    \else
    \begingroup
    \protected@edef\reserved@a{\chapterthumbformat}%
    \ifx\reserved@a\lastchapterthumbformat\else
    \stepcounter{chapterthumb}%
    \global\let\lastchapterthumbformat\reserved@a
    \fi
    \@tempcnta=\numexpr
    \dimexpr
    \paperheight
    -\firstchapterthumbskip
    -\chapterthumbwidth
    -\lastchapterthumbskip
    \relax / \dimexpr
    \chapterthumbskip
    \relax
    +1
    \relax
    \ifnum \value{chapterthumb}<\@tempcnta
    \else
    \setcounter{chapterthumb}{0}%
    \fi
    \vspace*{%
        \dimexpr
        \firstchapterthumbskip
        + ( \chapterthumbskip )
        * \value{chapterthumb}%
        - \baselineskip
        \relax
    }\par
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
    \ifodd\value{page}
    \hfill
    \makebox[0pt][r]{%
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\chapterthumb@box}}%
    \else
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\chapterthumb@box}}%
    \fi
    \endgroup
    \fi
    \fi
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{chapterthumb}
\setcounter{chapterthumb}{10000}
\newcommand*{\lastchapterthumbformat}{\relax}

\DeclareNewLayer[%
background,%
outermargin,%
contents=\chapterthumbbox
]{chapterthumb}

\newcommand*\EnableChapterthumb{%
    \IfLayerAtPageStyle{scrheadings}{chapterthumb}{}
    {\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb}}%
}
\newcommand*\DisableChapterthumb{%
    \RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{@everystyle@}{chapterthumb}%
}

\EnableChapterthumb

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\lipsum[1-6]

\chapter{Second}

\lipsum[7-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want diamonds with rounded corners, add `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}` after `\usepackage{tikz}` and replace the `\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}%` part with something like this:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner sep=2.5ex] (n) {\chapterthumbformat};
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \path[fill=chapterthumbboxcolor, rounded corners=2pt]
      (n.north) -- (n.west) -- (n.south) -- (n.east) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

[image]

Comment: I assume you put "would appear" in italics because you wondered why I didn't just try that myself. The reason is simply that I was not sure where to put the tikz environment. Thank you for posting a solution, it is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad that it suits your needs. Don't take the *would appear* too seriously—it's just that we often see “Is it possible to... ?” questions and, when it is quite clear for me that the answer is “yes (but this requires some work),” it is tempting to only answer “yes”... but I refrain from doing so. :-)

Comment: I see :) I'll make sure to just ask "How do I...?" in the future.